# how to remove ticks and values within name panels in hexplom() hexbin plot in R?

Tags: r, matrix, visualization, scatter-plot, lattice

I have followed this documentation https://rdrr.io/cran/hexbin/man/hexplom.html to build some scatter plot matrices for my continuous variables.

my data is like this

```
   dep_delay     temp    dewp   humid  wind_speed  precip  visib  date
1      39.02    28.04   64.43  11.50   13.24       0.00   10.00  2013-01-01
...
301     43      39.20   30.20  69.88   14.96       0.00    3.0   2013-03-25
...
1253    392     46.04   42.98  88.99   4.60        0.00    10.0  2013-12-21
```

[image]

my code

```
library(hexbin)
hexplom(~df_w_delays_num[1:7] , data = df_w_delays_num,
        xbins = 15, colramp = BTC, varnames = c("dep\ndelay", "temp", "dew", "humidity", "wind\nspeed","wind\ngust", "precipi\ntation", "visibility"))
```

Does anyone know how to remove the ticks and values obstructing the names of my variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `pscales = 0`. `pscales` is documented in `?lattice::panel.pairs`.